# Multiple aggs with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a noob with ES and I dont know how to resolve this simple scenario:

```
dataType value

    1 A
    1 A
    1 B
    2 B
    3 A
    3 A
    4 A
    4 B
```

I need to know how many datatypes only have 'A' value, how many only have 'B' value, and how many have both. The expected result for this example would be:

```
Only A = 1 (dataType 3)
Only B = 1 (dataType 2)
Both = 2 (dataTypes 1 and 4)
```

Could you help me ?  Thanks.

ChintanShah25 Hi, thank you very much for your quick response. I tried the code you have developed but not seem to work properly:

```
"Aggregations": {
           "Datatypes": {
                "Value": {
                "Both": 0,
                "Onlya": 1,
                "OnlyB": 1
            }
        }
    }
```

If I remove "reduce_script" I can debug, obtaining:

```
    "Aggregations": {
        "Datatypes": {
        "Value": [
                    [
                        [
                            "1"
                        ],
                        []
                    ],
                    [
                        []
                        []
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            "1"
                        ],
                        [
                            "1",
                            "2"
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            "4"
                        ],
                        []
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            "3"
                        ],
                        [
                            "4"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

Datatypes are grouped correctly, but it seems that they are separated into different buckets or sharps and the final step "reduce_script" fails.

Documentation "Scripted Metric" is poor and although'm testing not achieve the desired results.

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is tricky, It could be done by [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html). I created a test index and inserted the sample data you provided. The following query gives the results you want

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Datatypes": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "_agg['onlya'] = [];_agg['onlyb'] = [];",
        "map_script": "if (doc['value'].value == \"A\")
                         { _agg.onlya.add(doc['datatype'].value) };
                       if (doc['value'].value == \"B\")
                         { _agg.onlyb.add(doc['datatype'].value) };",
        "combine_script": "onlya = _agg['onlya'].unique();
                           onlyb = _agg['onlyb'].unique();
                           return[onlya, onlyb]",
        "reduce_script": "both_bucket=[];a_bucket=[];b_bucket=[];
                          for(a in _aggs)
                            {both_bucket=a[0].intersect(a[1]); 
                             a_bucket=a[0]-a[1];
                             b_bucket=a[1]-a[0]};
                             return ['Both' : both_bucket.size(),
                                     'OnlyA' : a_bucket.size(),
                                     'OnlyB' : b_bucket.size()];"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

This is the output I get

```
"aggregations": {
      "Datatypes": {
         "value": {
            "Both": 2,
            "OnlyA": 1,
            "OnlyB": 1
         }
      }
   }
```

You would need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) for this to work or put these scripts in [scripts folder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#modules-scripting).

During *init_script*, I am declaring two variables which will hold *datatype* value.

*map_script* goes through every document and adds the datatype to *onlya* if the value is "A" or to *onlyb*. You can replace the second if with else if you are certain that you will either have A or B

*combine_script* converts list to unique values so `[1,1,3,3,4]` becomes `[1,3,4]`

*reduce_script* gets results from all the shards. **Intersection** will give you bucket with both datatype value and **subtraction** will give you *only* part.`size()` gives you the length of the list. Remove the size method to get which datatype values matched.

Please go through the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html#_scope_of_scripts) to find more about how all these different phases of aggregation work

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work as I want. Thank you very much for your help.

```
  "aggs": {
    "Datatypes": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "_agg['onlya'] = [];_agg['onlyb'] = [];",
        "map_script": "valueAdd=doc['datatype'].value; if (doc['value'].value == \"a\") { _agg['onlya'].add(valueAdd) }; if (doc['value'].value == \"b\") { _agg['onlyb'].add(valueAdd) };",
        "combine_script": "onlya = _agg['onlya'].unique();                           onlyb = _agg['onlyb'].unique();                           return[onlya, onlyb]",
        "reduce_script": "a_bucket=[];b_bucket=[];for(a in _aggs){ a_bucket+=a[0]; b_bucket+=a[1];}; return ['Both' : a_bucket.intersect(b_bucket).size(), 'OnlyA' : (a_bucket-b_bucket).size(), 'OnlyB' : (b_bucket-a_bucket).size()];"

      }
    }
  }
```